# How to save an image in internal storage after cropping it?

Tags: android, android-intent, crop

Instead of getting image on onActivityResult, I want to save it in internal storage because now a days phones are coming with internal memory & some phone don't have sd card slots.

Here is my code

```
String TEMP_PHOTO_FILE = "temporary_holder.png";

//on button click
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");         
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputX", 600);
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputY", 600);
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scale", true);  
photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempUri());
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.toString());
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_WALLPAPER);

private Uri getTempUri() {
    return Uri.fromFile(getTempFile());
}

private File getTempFile() {
        File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(),TEMP_PHOTO_FILE);
        try {
           file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file;
    }

//onActivityResult
    File tempFile = getTempFile();
    String filePath= this.getFilesDir()+"/"+TEMP_PHOTO_FILE;
    ivWallpaper.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath));
```

Thank you all.

Comment: have a look at the docs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: @Raghunandan, thanks for reply btw I can save string/images in internal storage but I've no idea how to deal with this problem. Thanks

Comment: you can look at the docs and give it a try first.